# Как в numpy языка Python получить индекс элемента массива?

Tags: python, numpy

Генерирую список массивов array, которые представляют из себя наборы конечных разностей: их мы видим в столбцах с дельтами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот теперь задача. Пользователь задает порядок будущего полинома, и это определяет соответствующий столбец. В нем количество разностей различно: **мне надо получить индекс последнего числа (последней разности) в определенном столбце**. Пишу код, дающий ошибку:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Код:

```
def func(x):
    return np.sin(x)

def poly(order):
    # строим колонки X и Y:
    x_i_list = [round( (0.1*np.pi*i), 4 ) for i in range(0, 11)]
    y_i_list = []
    for x in x_i_list:
        y_i = round( (func(x)), 4 ) 
        y_i_list.append(y_i)

    # получаем дельты:
    n=order
    if n < len(y_i_list):
        result = [ np.diff(y_i_list, n=d) for d in np.arange(1, len(y_i_list)) ]
        print(result)
    else:
        print(f'Определите порядок полинома меньше {len(y_i_list)}')
    index = result.index(result[order-1][-1])
    return index
    
func(3)  # задается порядок полинома 3, 
         # то есть нужна разность по колонке с 3-й дельтой. 
         # Там индекс последней разности 7
```

Comment: А у вас так и задумано -  рекурсивная функция? А каким образом  и где вы эту рекурсию останавливаете? И вообще, как это может быть, что внешний (первичный) вызов функции предполагает передачу на вход порядка полинома (3), а внутренний, рекурсивный вызов - просто одного из значений списка, который к тому-же и генерируется внутри этой функции?

Comment: @passant, это моя невнимательность. Рекурсии нет. Просто название для функции примера здесь ошибочно оставил прежним, а внутренняя `func()`, на самом деле, содержит в себе код `return np.sin(x)`, принимая на вход x. Внес правку

Comment: Я рад, что вы заставили нас помучиться из за своей невнимательности. Кстати, вызов вашей функции poly() вы тоже не привели "по невнимательности"? Тем не менее ответ на ваш вопрос "как получить индекс последнего числа в определенном столбце" я уже час как привел в ответе ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индекс последнего элемента в ЛЮБОМ массиве numpy (или точнее -  в любом индексируемом объекте) если очень надо, ВСЕГДА можно получить как `last_index=len(arr)-1`.  Хотя в python благодаря соответствующему синтаксису оператора for необходимость в использовании такой конструкции весьма сомнительна.